# code stops at initialising self.cam = QCamera()

Tags: python, pyqt

I am using python3.5, pyqt5 and qt5. My problem may be simple but since i am getting no error and never experienced this problem i am writing this here. Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore , QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCamera, QCameraInfo, QMediaObject, QCameraViewfinderSettings, QCameraImageCapture
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QCameraViewfinder


class Camera(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent = QObject()):
        super(Camera, self).__init__(parent)
        print("TROLOLOL3")
        self.cam = QCamera()
        self.caminfo = QCameraInfo(self.cam)
        self.camvfind = QCameraViewfinder()
        self.camvfindset = QCameraViewfinderSettings()
        self.cammode = self.cam.CaptureMode(2)
        self.camimgcap = QCameraImageCapture(self.cam)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("TROLOLOL1")
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    print("TROLOLOL2")
    cam = Camera()
    print("TROLOLOL4")

    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

I deleted some irrelevant code for the overview. I tested when the code stops and at self.cam = QCamera() the code just stops, doesnt exit or shows a error. Why does this happen? This code compiled without error on Raspbian but now i am on Ubuntu Mate with Raspberry Pi 3.

If you have questions feel free to ask

Comment: what are `iniCamera` and `startVid`?

Comment: those are functions i deleted so the code is not that long. I have now deleted them so nobody gets confused anymore

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a [mcve], hide things, discourage me from helping you.

Comment: Does that updated code give you the same error? What version of Qt5 do you currently have?

Comment: well i guess thats what i did now. I am using Qt 5.9.3